# AWS EC2 High CPU alarms going off

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cpu-usage

I have a micro EC2 instance running windows 2008 R2.  I've been getting a lot of high CPU alarms going off lately, and when I log into the AWS management console I see that my CPU is practically pegged at 100%.  However, if I log into the instance and pull up task manager, my CPU looks like it's practically idling.  I've left task manager open for a while and took this  screenshot showing the differences between was AWS is reporting and what my instance looks like it's doing.  Suggestions?

[image: CPU Usage Graph]
(https://s3.amazonaws.com/caskerdbbucket/public/cpu.png)

PS: the update speed on task manager is set to "Low"

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on a t1.micro linux instance.

Comment: With the release of t2 instances, this probably has pretty much gone away, as we have more visibility as to when we might be getting throttled.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The data exposed by the operating system is often insufficient or misleading in virtualized environments like [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), and the reported percentage depends on your instance type and the under­ly­ing proces­sor core utilization (which usually doesn't match the virtualized hardware you are presented with from the hypervisor), amongst other things - what you are seeing is most likely caused by respective *CPU steal time* as exposed in most related Unix/Linux monitoring tools nowadays (but not on Windows, unfortunately, see my question [Is there a Windows equivalent of Unix 'CPU steal time'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/392216/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-unix-cpu-steal-time) for more regarding this problem) - see e.g. columns %steal or st in `sar` or `top`:

> **st -- Steal Time**
>   The amount of CPU 'stolen' from this virtual machine
>   by the hypervisor for other tasks (such as running another virtual
>   machine).

The blog post [EC2 monitoring: the case of stolen CPU](http://axibase.com/news/ec2-monitoring-the-case-of-stolen-cpu/) provides a nice exploration and illustration of this topic:

> When the top com­mand dis­plays 40% CPU busy but Cloud­Watch says the
>   server is maxed out at 100% — which side do you take? The answer is
>   sim­ple (Cloud­Watch is cor­rect, top is not) [...]

*CPU steal time* is particularly prevalent for the EC2 instance type t1.micro you are using, which can get heavily throttled by definition (usually ~97% steal time!), see [Micro Instances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html) for an extensive explanation and illustration of the concept - specifically, section [When the Instance Uses Its Allotted Resources](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html#when-instance-uses-allotted-resources) states:

> We expect your application to consume only a certain amount of CPU
>   resources in a period of time. If the application consumes more than
>   your instance's allotted CPU resources, **we temporarily limit the
>   instance so it operates at a low CPU level. If your instance continues
>   to use all of its allotted resources, its performance will degrade**. We
>   will increase the time we limit its CPU level, thus increasing the
>   time before the instance is allowed to burst again. *[emphasis mine]*

Accordingly, you might have outgrown the sustainable CPU usage profile for micro instances and either need to adjust your workload or switch to another instance type.

Comment: Excellent answer.  On a side note, my instance seems to be back to normal now.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it took a lot of time to find out a solution.
In the internet I did not found my case, so I share.

I discovered in the events list that were recorded many fraudulent login attempts. Task manager in that situation was reporting 30-40% of CPU usage (Cloud Watch 100%) and in the processes list were visible some winlogon.exe.
After changing the Remote Desktop port (3389 is the default) I had no more problems.
Now CPU usage in Cloud Watch is costantly 34-35%.

Hope this helps.